# Cant get new versions of expose-loader and style-loader to work

Tags: webpack

I really need help with figuring out why I cant resolve these errors:

```
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '/images/loading.gif'
```

The error origins from this line:

```
background: url(/images/loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

and then we have this:

```
_ERROR in ../node_modules/moment/moment.js (../node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js?moment!../node_modules/moment/moment.js)
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/expose-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Expose Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options misses the property 'exposes'. Should be:
   non-empty string | object { globalName, moduleLocalName?, override? } | [non-empty string | object { globalName, moduleLocalName?, override? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)_
```

I don't know where to turn for help. I have googled a lot, read through webpack documentation and guides. Followed several guides for upgrading to webpack 5.

What I am trying to do is updating from webpack 4 to 5. With that I updated expose-loader from 0.7.5 to 2.0.0 and css-loader from 3.5.3 to 5.2.4.
Now I cant get passed the above errors, I got several of them that points to different files, some off them are entry files.

For testing purposes I rolled back everything and just updated expose-loader to 1.0.3(2.0.0 only works with WP5) and css-loader to 5.2.4 and the same errors accured again on the same files. So my guess is that there must be something wrong how the webpack.config are configured.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "Bla"),
    entry: {
        bla: ["./bla"],
        bla_app: ["./bla_app"],
        bla2: ["@babel/polyfill", "./bla2"], //need @babel/polyfill for pechkin
        bla3: ["./bla3"],
        bla4: ["./bla4"],
        bla_5: ["@babel/polyfill", "./SinglePage/bla_5.js"], //need @babel/polyfill for redux/saga in IE
        bla_6: ["@babel/polyfill", "./SinglePage/bla_6.js"], //need @babel/polyfill for redux/saga in IE
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot", "build"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=100000",
            },
            // Expose jquery so that it is possible to use jquery in client that is
            // extended by plugins, for example bootstrap-select
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery",
            },
            // Expose jquery so that it is possible to use jquery in client that is
            // extended by plugins, for example bootstrap-select
            {
                test: /jquery\..*\.js/,
                loader: "imports?$=jquery,jQuery=jquery,this=>window",
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
        //........//
        },
    },
};
```

and the .dev.js

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./build",
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
});
```

How the same files look after I try to update to WP5:

```
const path = require("path");
const ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "Bla"),
    plugins: [
        new ESLintPlugin({
            extensions: ["js", "jsx"],
            exclude: ["node_modules"]
        }),
        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        //  $: 'jquery',
        //  jQuery: 'jquery',
        // }),
        // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        //  _: 'lodash',
        // }),
    ],
    entry: {
     bla: ["./bla"],
    bla_app: ["./bla_app"],
    bla2: ["@babel/polyfill", "./bla2"], //need @babel/polyfill for pechkin
    bla3: ["./bla3"],
    bla4: ["./bla4"],
    bla_5: ["@babel/polyfill", "./SinglePage/bla_5.js"], //need @babel/polyfill for redux/saga in IE
    bla_6: ["@babel/polyfill", "./SinglePage/bla_6.js"], //need @babel/polyfill for redux/saga in IE
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: 'auto',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot", "build"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "url-loader",
                    options: {
                        limit: 100000,
                    }
                }],
                type: 'javascript/auto',
            },
            {
                // Expose jquery so that it is possible to use jquery in client that is
                // extended by plugins, for example bootstrap-select
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "expose-loader",
                options: {
                    exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
                },
            },
            // Expose jquery so that it is possible to use jquery in client that is
            // extended by plugins, for example bootstrap-select
            {
                test: /jquery\..*\.js/,
                use: "imports?$=jquery,jQuery=jquery,this=>window",
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
        //........//
        },
    },
};
```

.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./build"),
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fyi, the issue with the css file not resloving the url() was solved by adding this that disable url() resolving:

```
options: {
            url: false,
        },
```

end result:

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    url: false,
                },
            }],
        },
```

You can read about it here:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#boolean

Still having issue with the  `options misses the property 'exposes'.` when updating expose-loader....

Edit:
We had inline exposes in the codebase like this:

```
import "expose-loader?moment!moment";
```

changed to this:

```
import $ from "expose-loader?exposes=moment!moment";
```

A huge thanks to "alexander-akait" that help me solved it:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader/issues/129